# How to interpret marginal likelihood definition?

Tags: bayesian, likelihood

Say we have a Beta-Bernoulli model where $X_i$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli variables, $p(X_i=1)=\theta$, and $\theta\sim\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$.

The marginal likelihood is defined as

$$
p(X)=\int p(X|\theta)p(\theta)d\theta
$$

Consider a concrete $X=(1,1)$.

One way to compute $p(X)$, described in 
"Machine Learning. A Probabilistic Perspective" by Kevin P. Murphy, is

$$p(X)=p(X_1)p(X_2|X_1)=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}\cdot\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha+\beta+1}$$

On the other hand, since $X_i$ are independent, we should be able to say that $P(X_2|X_1)=p(X_2)$,

$$p(X)=p(X_1)p(X_2|X_1)=\left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}\right)^2$$

I assume that Kevin's interpretation is the correct one, but does it mean I can no longer apply the familiar facts from the probability theory such as $p(X_2|X_1)=p(X_2)$ for independent variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent *conditional* on $\theta$:
$$
p(X_1,X_2|\theta) = p(X_1|X_2,\theta)\,p(X_2|\theta) = p(X_1|\theta)\,p(X_2|\theta),
$$
But they are not unconditionally independent:
$$
\begin{split}
p(X_1,X_2) &= \int p(X_1|\theta)\,p(X_2|\theta)\,p(\theta)\,d\theta \\
&= \begin{cases}
 \frac{\alpha  (\alpha
   +1)}{(\alpha +\beta ) (\alpha
   +\beta +1)} & X_1=1\land X_2=1
   \\
 \frac{\alpha  \beta }{(\alpha
   +\beta ) (\alpha +\beta +1)} &
   \left(X_1=0\land
   X_2=1\right)\lor
   \left(X_1=1\land X_2=0\right)
   \\
 \frac{\beta  (\beta +1)}{(\alpha
   +\beta ) (\alpha +\beta +1)} &
   X_1=0\land X_2=0
\end{cases}.
\end{split}
$$
Moral: it is important to keep track of the conditioning arguments.